# Why parallel foreach is strangely slow with solve?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have tried to improve efficiency of my code by using the parallel `foreach` loop from the `doParralel` library. However, I have found that it takes considerably larger amount of time for the parallel code to complete. I have managed to narrow down the problem to the lines optimizing (`nloptr`) a function involving matrix inversion. Can anyone help me to find out why I get the following results? This the exact script I am using to reproduce the problem

```
library(doParallel)
if (!exists('cluster')) {
  cl <<- makeCluster(2)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  }

pt <- function(n,t,m,par=TRUE) {
  if (par)
    foreach(1:t) %dopar% {
      for(i in 1:m)
        solve(matrix(runif(n*n),n,n))
      NULL
    }
  else
    foreach(1:t) %do% {
      for(i in 1:m)
        solve(matrix(runif(n*n),n,n))
      NULL
    }
}
```

Then,

```
> system.time(pt(200,6,10,FALSE))
 user  system elapsed 
0.904   1.667   0.330 
> system.time(pt(200,6,10,TRUE))
 user  system elapsed 
0.133   0.012  33.918
```

Smaller user time - fine. But why the incredibly high total elapsed time?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C                 
 [3] LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8       
 [5] LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8      
 [7] LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8          LC_NAME=pl_PL.UTF-8          
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=pl_PL.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=pl_PL.UTF-8     
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=pl_PL.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
[1] doParallel_1.0.11 iterators_1.0.9   foreach_1.4.4     rkward_0.6.3     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3      codetools_0.2-14
```

Comment: Is it possible the timing mechanism is taking into account when the thread pool (or whatever is backing `foreach`) shuts down, and the pool has a 30 second timeout? Shot In the dark, because I don't know R.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, In fact for the full code the difference was a lot larger 1min : 15min. BTW, I am using two cores.

Comment: For me, the parallel version with 2,3,4,5,6,7 cores is always faster then the normal foreach. By a factor of  2-4. I checked the times with `microbenchmark`.

Comment: Same as @SeGa. You may want to give us all the code you use and some info on your system.

Comment: I run ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2630QM CPU @ 2.00GHz, 4 physical cores I guess. R is R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10). What other details could be relevant?

Comment: @SeGa The code I run is exactly the one mentioned, wrapped in a function in order to make it easy to call `system.time`. I checked the code on a newer windows machine, with ms R, and the `%dopar%` is indeed faster (???). On Ubuntu, when I run the parallel version, the fan starts to work hard for a minute, like it did some extreme computations. It look like a problem of my specific system. Does anyone have an idea, what could be causing this? Where to search for clues?

Comment: I had similar results on a Linux system with R 3.5.0 linked against MKL. When I switched back to OpenBLAS, the problem went away. There was not much speed up, though. You can see the used BLAS/LAPACK in `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: @RalfStubner I am not sure. My `sessionInfo()` does not mention any BLAS or MKL. I did install Intel Mkl some time ago, however, it didn't work well and I had to `timeshift` the system, so I think it's no longer there. Otherwise, it's just out of the box ubuntu installation of R.Although, parallel matrix inversion might go into way

Comment: It was an observation, not an explanation attempt. How about you [edit] your question to include the output of `sessionInfo()` as well as the *complete* code you are using?

Comment: @RalfStubner ... Although, parallel matrix inversion might go into way of `foreach`, there are two things: 1. `foreach` is told, as I understand it, to use a cluster of 2 workers by `makeCluster(2)` and the CPU offers 4 physical/8 SMT cores; 2. it's specifically about solve, no problems with `%*%` or `det()`.